# How to import flat colors into my project in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to use flat colors in my Gradient. I was wondering how can I use a flat color in my flutter project. What I mean in flat color is just like in https://flatuicolors.com/

```dart
body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.blueAccent]
          )
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use flatuicolors as there is no plugin like for fontawesome icons. So you can just copy color codes from flatuicolors and use it in your dart code.

```
For Ex :

       body:Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [Color(0xff25CCF7), Color(0xff55E6C1)]),
              ),
            ),
```

You can use **Color()** class for using hex color codes like #25CCF7 & #55E6C1. You can add hex codes after **prefix 0xff** in Color class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do, Use color as given below.

```dart
Color mFlatColor = Color(0xFFF47D15);
```

Use Color HAX value as given above and you can create a custom color. Use it as given below, you can directly define the inside gradient as well.

```dart
body:Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [mFlatColor, Color(0xff55E6C1)]),
              ),
            ),
```